# Cannot Reload React Native App on Mobile Using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to React Native, I am using Expo for building react native project and when I make any change in app I can see reload message in browser but the app does not reload in mobile (Note: I am using android mobile). TIA

[image: See this Image]

Comment: are you using it through USB or LAN?

Comment: How to use it with USB there are three options Tunnel,LAN and LOCAL. LAN and local giving me timeout error even though i am on same wifi. I am using TUNNEL

Comment: to use it with USB you'd select LOCAL and then 'Start on android mobile' (something like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it I had both **Hot Reloading** and **Live Reload** enabled in Expo Mobile App. I turned off **Live Reload**. Now its working great using Tunnel option. Thanks for help @kivul

Answer (score 2):

you can press refresh like below image to reload app in phone

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/up-and-running/

[image]